# Yii2 Full page load to modal div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, yii2, bootstrap-modal, active-form

I try to load ActiveForm by modal boostrap
but instead form modal load full page
In the picture is 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXimi.jpg)

Layout: main.php

```
...
    yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
        'header' => '<span id="modalHeaderTitle"></span>',
        'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
        'id' => 'modal',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
        'closeButton' =>['tag'=>'close', 'label'=> 'Zamknij'],
        'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 1, 'keyboard' =>True]
    ]);
    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
    yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
    ?>
 ...
```

view: _form.php

```
<div class="category-form">
Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Button for start modal:

```
<?= Html::button('Nowa kategoria', ['value' => Url::to(['category/create']), 'title' => 'Nowa kategoria', 'class' => 'showModalButton btn btn-success']); ?>
```

modal.js

```
$(function(){
      $(document).on('click', '.showModalButton', function(){
        if ($('#modal').data('bs.modal').isShown) {
            $('#modal').find('#modalContent')
                    .load($(this).attr('value'));
            document.getElementById('modalHeaderTitle').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
        } else {

            $('#modal').modal('show')
                    .find('#modalContent')
                    .load($(this).attr('value'));

            document.getElementById('modalHeaderTitle').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
        }
    });
});
```

Please help find a error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the action in the controller that renders the page not to use the full page layout. You should be able to do that by setting.

```
$this->layout = false;
```

In the controller so it does not use any layout. Or you can set specific layout:

```
$this->layout = 'modalLayout.php';
```

And create a file called `modalLayout.php` in the `layouts` folder that contains only the things that you want as the layout for the modal.

After you get the modal with the content you want, add a new question here and ask why your `ActiveForm` is not working properly (P.S.: because it may not be instantiated properly).